# Get date in certain timezone javascript

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

I have all the date components of a new Date() function in javascript.

```
new Date(yyyy,mm,dd,hours,minutes,seconds,milliseconds);
```

The date components are obtained from a Malaysian server using jsp. I am not in Malaysia so when I do
 new Date(yyyy,mm,dd,hours,minutes,seconds,milliseconds);
 it provides me the time in my local area. How can I get it in Malaysian time zone?

Comment: Javascript is client side....

Comment: @Idris: it can also be server-side with node.js...

Comment: @Idris - Doesn't have to be.  You can run JS server-side as well.  Though in this case I think you're right.

Comment: Well it was never stated, or tagged. So I'd assume its just plain client side JS. Guess we'll just have to wait for OP to confirm @djikay

Comment: @Idris: I agree, I just wanted to mention that, in general, it doesn't *have* to be client-side, but in this case you're probably right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In JSP**, you can use [JSTL Formatting Tags - Internationalization](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakw.html#bnalc) that provides a set of tags for parsing and formatting locale-sensitive numbers and dates.

The `timeZone` tag establishes the time zone (specified with the `value` attribute) to be used by any nested `formatDate` tags.

Sample code: (*Change the timezone as per your need*)

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>

<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date" />
<c:set var="timeZone" value="GMT-8"/>

Date in the current time zone:
<fmt:formatDate value="${today}" type="both" /><br/>

Date in the GMT-8 time zone:
<fmt:timeZone value="${timeZone}">
      <fmt:formatDate value="${today}" timeZone="${timeZone}" type="both" />
</fmt:timeZone>
```

---

Find complete sample code [here](http://codejava.net/java-ee/jstl/jstl-format-tag-timezone) and [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_timezone_tag.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I think without a library you won't have a good time doing such things, i.e. it's not supported and `Date` is only aware of local time. I would suggest having a look at the timezone module of momentjs: http://momentjs.com/timezone/.